# Como passar uma lista de inteiros como parâmetros do dapper?

Tags: c#, dapper

Estou tentando passar um parâmetro que é uma lista de inteiros, isso deve ser anexado a consulta 
na clausula IN do sql server, mas não estou sabendo como usar com o [DAPPER](https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper).

Tentei fazer da seguinte forma.

```
var adesao = Adesao.Repositorio.Obter(adesaoId.Value);
if (adesao != null)
{
    adesoes = string.Join(",", Adesao.Repositorio.ObterTodasAdesoes(adesao));
    var ids = new[] { adesoes.Split(',').Select(Int32.Parse).ToList() };
    adesoesids = new { ids };

    sb.AppendWhere(" e.AdesaoId IN (@adesoes) ");
}
```

//Montagem dos parametros;

```
var parametros = new
{
    adesoes = adesoesids,
};

return SessionDapper.Query<Extrato>(sb.ToString(), parametros).ToList();
```

Se eu passar a string adesoes direto até chegar da forma que deveria só que do tipo string onde deveria ser inteiros como (1,2,3,4 ...) esta indo ('1,2,3,4 ..')

```
adesoes = string.Join(",", Adesao.Repositorio.ObterTodasAdesoes(adesao));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sua primeira abordagem me parece correta. O problema é que `ids` não é uma lista de inteiros e sim um *array* de lista de inteiros. Além disso, você cria um objeto `adesoesids` para colocar estes dados.

Basicamente, seu objeto `parametros` está assim

```
parametros: {
    adesoes: {
        ids: [
            [1, 2, 3, 4]
        ]
    }
}
```

O Dapper espera que o parâmetro usado na cláusula `In` seja um `IEnumerable`.

Seu código deveria ser assim:

```
var ids = adesoes.Split(',').Select(Int32.Parse).ToList();

// Perceba que tirei o 'new [] { }' e que não é necessário criar um objeto

var parametros = new
{
    adesoes = ids,
};

return SessionDapper.Query<Extrato>(sb.ToString(), parametros).ToList();
```

Comment: Tentei fazer assim, mas retorna erro de sintaxe, se não monto a query com esse filtro ele passa de boa, é algo de errado nesse parâmetro mesmo.

Comment: Erro de sintaxe? Que erro?

Comment: vou continuar usando o string.Format ele monta e esta funcionado normalmente sb.AppendWhere(string.Format(" e.AdesaoId IN ({0}) ", string.Join(",", adesoes)));

Comment: Não há muita especificação no erro só .. .Incorrect syntax near ','.

Comment: Eu acho que a estrutura do seu objeto de filtro ainda não está correta. Este ocorre quando? Ao executar a query?

Comment: isso, se eu tiro a parte ,  sb.AppendWhere(" e.AdesaoId IN (@adesoes) "); funcionar normalmente .

Comment: vi algumas soluções como, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39523414/c-sharp-dapper-error-when-parameter-is-listint-no-mapping-exists-from-object-t  e https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12723922/dapper-adddynamicparams-for-in-statement-with-dynamic-parameter-name onde eles passar o arry diretamente como um único parâmetro.

Comment: Você tem como mostrar um print da estrutura do objeto de filtro?